# On Visual Studio 2019, how to debug pure C++ and CLI C++ in a C++ Debug program?

Tags: visual-studio, c++17, c++-cli, visual-studio-debugging

I want to debug a C++ MFC/CLI program developped on Visual Studio 2019.

Until now, I can debug C++ native (MFC) code.

`DebugType` in Debug panel is set to `Auto`.

All breakpoints in C++/CLI modules are flagged as inactive (a red circle with an interrogation character in a yellow triangle).

After having changed `DebugType` from `Auto` to 'Mixed (.Net Framework), Visual Studio, when starting a debug session, is displaying following warning box.

[image]

But my build is in DEBUG mode !

What is happening ?

What must I do to debug pure C++ **AND** CLI C++ code ?

PS: I have also tried to debug in only C++/CLI code, but Visual Studio 2019 is displaying same message !

Comment: Why did you want to  change `DebugType ` to `Mixed(.Net Framework)`? Did you debug mfc code in net framework project? Also, is your mfc project a dynamic library project?

Comment: I try to debug a old C++ program that uses MFC to display forms using DOC/VIEW tempate and that is using only C++/CLI to display .Net Dialog WinForms. At begin of my program written in MFC, the program load a WinForm dialog for Login that call a pure C++ for Oracle connection library (OCILIB). I can debug C++ before calling WinForm dialog, I can debug OCILIB code debelopped in pure C++, but all breakpoints put in LOGIN Dialog Winform are not interpreted by debugger. So I have change DebugType from Auto to Mixed because (for me) this C++ is a mixed program !

Comment: any update about this issue?

Comment: sorry, but it is to hot/warm to work where my PC is. I come back in 2 or 3 days when temperature is lower. I don't forget you and I'm interesting to test your proposal to see if it solve my problem.

Comment: We will wait for your any reponse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> On Visual Studio 2019, how to debug pure C++ and CLI C++ in a C++
> Debug program?

Since I do not have your project and cannot troubleshoot the issue quickly unless you provide a sample.

You can try the following suggestions:

**Suggestions**

**1)** try to reset all settings by **Tools**-->**Import and Export Settings**-->**Reset All Settings**

**2)** disable any third party extensions under **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions** in case one of them causes the behavior.

**3)** check `Use Managed Compatibility Mode` option, `Enable .NET Framework source stepping` option and `Suppress JIT optimization on module load (Managed only)` option under **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Debugging**-->**General**.

**4)** close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder, `Debug` folder from the solution folder and also `Debug` folder in the project folder. Then restart your project to test again.

Comment: I have tested again with DebugType=Mixed and this solution solve my problem. I can now add breakpoints in pure C++ part and also in CLI/C++ part.

Comment: "Suppress JIT optimization on module load (Managed only)" worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm putting this here because it might help someone in the future, and because it's completely nuts.
I've followed all instructions I could find, including the ones on this question, reinstalled VS twice, with different versions, and nothing.
What solved for me was to simply delete the lines of code and write them again.
Yes.
I know.